# Get data from parrent component

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 components:

header.vue
nav.vue

In header i have button, when i click, in nav change class. But i cant get parent component :( How to do this?

index.pug:

```
.g#global
            frameheader
            .frame
                navigation(:navhidden="hiddenNav", :mobileaside="asideMobile", :links=navJson) 
                .frame__content
                    block content
```

main.js:

```
import navigation from '../vue/components/nav.vue';
import frameheader from '../vue/components/frameheader.vue';

Vue.component("navigation", navigation);
Vue.component("frameheader", frameheader);

Vue.use(VueCookie);

var global = new Vue({
    el: "#global",
    data() {
        return {
            hiddenNav: false,
            asideMobile: false
        }
    }
})
```

Header.vue:

In header i have two buttons, who need to change data `hiddenNav` and `asideMobile` in main.js

```
<template lang="pug">
    header.header
        .header__left(:class="{'hidden-aside': this.$root.$emit(hiddenNav)}")
            a.header__logo(href="")
                img(src="img/logo_smart.png", alt="")
            button.header__nav(@click="hiddenNav = !hiddenNav")
                span
            button.header__nav.header__nav_mobile(@click="asideMobile = !asideMobile" :class="{'active': asideMobile}")
                span

</template>

<script>

import VueSlideUpDown from 'vue-slide-up-down'

export default {
    name: 'frameheader',
    data() {
        return {
            active: null,
            val: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeMenuType() {
            this.$root.$emit(hiddenNav, true);
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Nav.vue:

In .frame__aside i try to read parrent data drom main.js, but its not work (

```
<template lang="pug">
   .frame__aside( :class="{'hidden-aside': navhidden, 'active': mobileaside }")
</template>
<script>
    import VueSlideUpDown from 'vue-slide-up-down'
    export default {
        name: 'navigation',
        data() {
            return {
                active: null,
                val: false
            }
        },
        props: {
            navhidden: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            mobileaside: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the markup where you use these components (ie. the `#global` div)

Comment: Thanks, I added at the top

Comment: Man, the readability of `pug` is just awful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish what you want is to take advantage of Vue's [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

In your `#global` template, we need to add listeners for `toggle-hidden-nav` and `toggle-mobile-aside`:

```
#global.g
  frameheader(@toggle-hidden-nav='hiddenNav = !hiddenNav', @toggle-aside-mobile='asideMobile = !asideMobile', :hidden-nav='hiddenNav', :mobile-aside='asideMobile')
  .frame
    navigation(:nav-hidden='hiddenNav', :mobile-aside='asideMobile')
    .frame__content
```

**NOTE:** I've also updated props and events to use kebab case per the Vue docs (see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) and [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)).

---

In your `header` component, we need to

1. `$emit` the custom events when the buttons are clicked
2. Pass `hiddenNav` and `asideMobile` as props (for `:class` binding)

```
<template lang="pug">
header.header
  .header__left(:class="{'hidden-aside': hiddenNav}")
    a.header__logo(href='')
      img(src='img/logo_smart.png', alt='')
    button.header__nav(@click="$emit('toggle-hidden-nav')")
      span
    button.header__nav.header__nav_mobile(@click="$emit('toggle-aside-moble')", :class="{'active': mobileAside}")
      span
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  props: {
    hiddenNav: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    mobileAside: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

Finally, I'd fix your the class bindings in the `nav` component as well:

```
<template lang="pug">
   .frame__aside( :class="{'hidden-aside': navHidden, 'active': mobileAside }")
</template>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!